# XMS - how to restore connection to WebSphere SIBus after network outage

Tags: c#, websphere-8

I'm connecting to a JMS queue. The queue is hosted by WebSphere Application Server (version 8.0.0.5), using SIBus.

I have a simple program to reproduce some problematic behavior, it is written in C# and uses XMS (IBM's .NET API) to connect to the queue. **Note**: I obtained the IBM.XMS dlls from here: [MQC71: WebSphere MQ V7.1 Clients](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412)

The scenario is this:

1. run the program (use an empty queue, so it sits waiting on a blocking Receive call)
2. disconnect network (unplug ethernet)
3. after a few minutes, the Receive call throws an exception
4. the program attempts to connect anew
5. this fails due to the network being down
6. ...let it loop a bit to verify this error keeps occurring
7. restore the network (plug in ethernet)
8. the same error continues to occur (verified with WireShark that no network traffic occurs during the connectionFactory.CreateConnection() call)

**So, the question is:** why does the CreateConnection() call do nothing (does not send any packets) but fail?

```
using IBM.XMS;
using System;

namespace SimpleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string queueURI = "queue://your.details.GoHereDearReader";
                    string providerEndpoint = "1.2.3.4:1234";
                    string targetTransportChain = "InboundBasicMessaging";
                    string busName = "some_bus_name";

                    XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WPM);
                    IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
                    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WPM_PROVIDER_ENDPOINTS, providerEndpoint);
                    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WPM_TARGET_TRANSPORT_CHAIN, targetTransportChain);
                    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WPM_BUS_NAME, busName);

                    Log("Connecting...");
                    using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
                    {
                        using (var session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge))
                        {
                            using (var destination = session.CreateQueue(queueURI))
                            {
                                destination.SetIntProperty(XMSC.DELIVERY_MODE, XMSC.DELIVERY_NOT_PERSISTENT);
                                connection.Start();

                                using (IMessageConsumer consumer =  session.CreateConsumer(destination))
                                {
                                    Log("Receiving...");
                                    IMessage recvMsg = consumer.Receive();
                                    Log("recvMsg:" + recvMsg);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log(e.ToString());
                }
                Log("Sleeping some before consuming more...");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
            }//while
        }//Main

        static void Log(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + "--------------------------  " + text);
        }

    }
}
```

And some output:

```
16:38:19.483--------------------------  Connecting...
16:38:19.936--------------------------  Receiving...
16:43:31.952--------------------------  IBM.XMS.XMSException: EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0022
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0022.explanation
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0022.useraction
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.Connection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.Connection.Dispose()
   at SimpleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestJMSDequeue\SimpleTest\Program.cs:line 43

Linked Exception : IBM.XMS.SIB.JFAP.JFapConversationClosedException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.SIB.JFAP.JFapConversationClosedException' was thrown.
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.JFAP.ConversationImpl.Send(IByteBuffer[] data, JFAPSegmentType segmentType, UInt16 requestNumber, IoPriority priority, Boolean pooledBufferHint, IReceiveListener recvListener, ISendListener sendListener, Object state)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.JFAP.ConversationImpl.RequestReplyExchange(IByteBuffer[] data, JFAPSegmentType segmentType, UInt16 requestNumber, IoPriority priority, Boolean pooledBufferHint)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.JFAP.ConversationImpl.RequestReplyExchange(IByteBuffer data, JFAPSegmentType segmentType, UInt16 requestNumber, IoPriority priority, Boolean pooledBufferHint)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Comms.Client.JFAPCommunicator.RequestReplyExchange(IByteBuffer data, JFAPSegmentType sendSegType, MessagePriority priority, Boolean canPoolOnReceive)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Comms.Client.ConnectionProxy.Close()
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.Connection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
16:43:31.952--------------------------  Sleeping some before consuming more...
16:43:41.967--------------------------  Connecting...
Exception  : System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.43.41.967444.txt
Exception  : IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.TrmFirstContactMessageImpl.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.ClientBootstrapHandler.Connect(IClientConnection clientConnection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.43.41.983044.txt
16:43:41.983--------------------------  IBM.XMS.XMSException: EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.explanation
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.useraction
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at SimpleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestJMSDequeue\SimpleTest\Program.cs:line 26

Linked Exception : IBM.XMS.Core.SIResourceException: CWSIT0006E: It is not possible to connect to bus your_bus_name_here because the following bootstrap servers could not be contacted  1.2.3.4:1234:BootstrapBasicMessaging and the following bootstrap servers returned an error condition . See previous messages for the reason for each bootstrap server failure.
The client cannot connect to the bus. This situation may be due to configuration problems, network problems or it may be that none of the required bootstrap servers or messaging engines are currently available.
Ensure that the network is working correctly and that the required bootstrap servers and messaging engines are available. ---> IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException' was thrown.
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Comms.Client.ClientSideConnection.Connect(ConnectionProperties cp, IClientComponentHandshake cch, SICoreConnectionProperties siProps)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String username, String password, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
16:43:41.983--------------------------  Sleeping some before consuming more...
16:43:51.998--------------------------  Connecting...
Exception  : System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.43.51.998262.txt
Exception  : IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.TrmFirstContactMessageImpl.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.ClientBootstrapHandler.Connect(IClientConnection clientConnection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.43.51.998262.txt
16:43:51.998--------------------------  IBM.XMS.XMSException: EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.explanation
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.useraction
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at SimpleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestJMSDequeue\SimpleTest\Program.cs:line 26

Linked Exception : IBM.XMS.Core.SIResourceException: CWSIT0006E: It is not possible to connect to bus your_bus_name_here because the following bootstrap servers could not be contacted  1.2.3.4:1234:BootstrapBasicMessaging and the following bootstrap servers returned an error condition . See previous messages for the reason for each bootstrap server failure.
The client cannot connect to the bus. This situation may be due to configuration problems, network problems or it may be that none of the required bootstrap servers or messaging engines are currently available.
Ensure that the network is working correctly and that the required bootstrap servers and messaging engines are available. ---> IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException' was thrown.
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Comms.Client.ClientSideConnection.Connect(ConnectionProperties cp, IClientComponentHandshake cch, SICoreConnectionProperties siProps)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String username, String password, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
16:43:51.998--------------------------  Sleeping some before consuming more...
16:44:02.013--------------------------  Connecting...
Exception  : System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.44.02.013479.txt
Exception  : IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.MessageEncodeFailedException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: UniqueLinkObject no seen on handshake.
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.SchemaManager.SendSchemas(ICommsConnection connection, JMFSchema[] schemas)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.JsMsgObject.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.Formats.MFP.SIB.TrmFirstContactMessageImpl.Encode(Object connection)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.ClientBootstrapHandler.Connect(IClientConnection clientConnection)
FFDC to xmsffdc8416_2013.03.08T10.44.02.013479.txt
16:44:02.013--------------------------  IBM.XMS.XMSException: EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.explanation
EXCEPTION_RECEIVED_CWSIA0241.useraction
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at SimpleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\TestJMSDequeue\SimpleTest\Program.cs:line 26

Linked Exception : IBM.XMS.Core.SIResourceException: CWSIT0006E: It is not possible to connect to bus your_bus_name_here because the following bootstrap servers could not be contacted  1.2.3.4:1234:BootstrapBasicMessaging and the following bootstrap servers returned an error condition . See previous messages for the reason for each bootstrap server failure.
The client cannot connect to the bus. This situation may be due to configuration problems, network problems or it may be that none of the required bootstrap servers or messaging engines are currently available.
Ensure that the network is working correctly and that the required bootstrap servers and messaging engines are available. ---> IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException: Exception of type 'IBM.XMS.Core.SIConnectionLostException' was thrown.
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Comms.Client.ClientSideConnection.Connect(ConnectionProperties cp, IClientComponentHandshake cch, SICoreConnectionProperties siProps)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.Bootstrap(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties, ClientAttachProperties cap)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(Credentials credentials, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.SIB.Trm.TrmSICoreConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String username, String password, SICoreConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at IBM.XMS.Impl.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String userName, String password)
16:44:02.013--------------------------  Sleeping some before consuming more...
```

Note that in the above output I unplugged the network shortly after "Receiving..." and plugged it in again at 16:43:52, but the errors continued after that until I killed the program.

Answer (score 0):

It reads like the ConnectionFactory does not reset it's state properly when the network becomes available again.

I have scoured the reference manual for any hint of a reset function on the factory - but havn't found one.
I would try this however: Move the `GetInstance(...)` and `createConnectionFactory()` out of the loop, as well as the `SetStringProperty()` lines.

If that doesn't work I cannot see why your client would not work.
Have you considered if this is a problem with the server? Which ethernet cable did you unplug? the one connected to the client or the server? If it was the server, does the same problem occur when you unplug the client cable?
If you restart the program, will it work then?

Comment: Upon restart, the program connects to the queue fine. I unplugged the network cable connecting the client to the network.

Comment: Then either the suggestion to move some lines outside the loop should work - or it looks like it is most likely a bug in the framework.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (moving creation and initialization of connectionFactory outside of the loop). The same error condition results. Note that I would accept a bug report with IBM as a sufficient answer if you have a customer account with IBM and can create it. If there's no workaround/fix then I will start looking into how to unload/reload the XMS DLLs (hoping that is equivalent to restarting the application).

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But I did manage to find you [this](http://www.jamestheintegrationguy.com/using-net-wcf-to-connect-to-websphere-mq/). I'm not sure if it will help - but it could.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but maybe it will be still helpful.

You receive this error after you created 65.535 connections. It doesn't matter if you close the connection / dispose the object.

I see the following solutions:

1.) You can either create a connection once and reuse the connection for all your operations on the queue, until the connection breaks. Then you have to do a reconnect. (yes that's bad and against the common patterns. I wouldn't advice to do this)

2.) There is a bugfix for the version 8.0.0.6 available. *EDIT: APAR #(IJ01244)*
I don't know yet when it will included into future releases.
I guess you can contact the IBM support and refer to this PMR ID to receive an updated version of the IBM.XMS.SIB.dll

Hope this helps.